# Nginx proxy for Tomcat killing connection after approx 17 minutes

Tags: java, tomcat, nginx

I have Nginx 1.10.2 acting as a reverse proxy for a Spring Boot 2 application using Tomcat 8.5.28 running on Ubuntu 16.04.1. One of our endpoints streams lots of data back to the client. After approximately 17 minutes of continuous streaming it seems that Nginx kills the connection.

In the Java app I get:

```
org.apache.catalina.connector.ClientAbortException: java.net.SocketTimeoutException
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.realWriteBytes(OutputBuffer.java:356) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar!/:8.5.28]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.appendByteArray(OutputBuffer.java:785) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar!/:8.5.28]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.append(OutputBuffer.java:721) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar!/:8.5.28]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.writeBytes(OutputBuffer.java:391) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar!/:8.5.28]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.write(OutputBuffer.java:369) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar!/:8.5.28]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteOutputStream.write(CoyoteOutputStream.java:96) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar!/:8.5.28]
```

In the Nginx error log:

```
[error] 18876#18876: *70244827 readv() failed (104: Connection reset by peer) while reading upstream, client: xxx, server: xxx, request: "GET xxx", host: "xxx"
```

On the client (curl):

```
curl: (18) transfer closed with outstanding read data remaining
```

I have been testing this using curl and --rate-limit to slow down the transfer enough to take more than 17 mins. It works if it gets done in under 17 mins or if I bypass Nginx and connect directly to the Java app.

Nginx virtual host:

```
upstream grouse_local {
    server 127.0.0.1:8143;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name ...;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/grouse_local_access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/grouse_local_error.log;
    ssl_certificate ...;
    ssl_certificate_key ...;

    add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains; preload" always;

    gzip on;
    gzip_proxied any;
    gzip_types text/css text/plain text/xml application/xml application/javascript application/x-javascript text/javascript application/json text/x-json text/csv;
    gzip_vary on;
    gzip_min_length 1000;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://grouse_local/;
        proxy_next_upstream error timeout http_502;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        set_real_ip_from ...;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }
}
```

Any ideas? I don't want to add "don't stream for more than 17 mins" to our API docs :)

Comment: Don't know whether it will help, but 17 minutes is 4 seconds short of 1,024 seconds.

Comment: Hmm. Last test was 17m13s with approx 5 secs to start so it could be a 1024 sec timeout.

Comment: I also tried connecting to Nginx via 127.0.0.1 with 'Host: xxx' header instead of using the external interface and it still failed